# Re-deploying AWS Ingress keeps binning my AWS ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, aws-alb

We're using a AWS ALB Ingress controller to manage our entry to the K8S cluster we have.

Every time we add a new ingress rule it seems to bin our ALB and re-provision it, which in turn will take everything down - are we doing something wrong?

Thanks,

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: "dv1-ingress"
  namespace: "dv1"
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
  labels:
    app: dv1-ingress
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /derivative-cost-new/*
            backend:
              serviceName: "derivative-cost-new-published-uk-service"
              servicePort: 80
```

Comment: Have you tried using `kubectl edit ingress dv1-ingress` (not sure if this works)

Comment: How many replicas do you have of ALB Ingress Controller ?
If you have a cluster under high load, I would recommend to go for High-Availability deployment of ALB Ingress (3 replicas at minimum). Can you post also the output of "kubectl describe deploy <ALB_Ingress_Controller_Deployment>"